# 108 Surya Namaskar - What are they counting

Tags: yoga, reps, sets

I'm not sure if I should post here, or on Hinduism forum, as it is Yoga and Power workout.

I have been doing Surya Namaskar in the morning. I am comfortable at 30 rounds.

But according to tradition, they say reach to 108.

Just now, I read this article, http://www.stylecraze.com/articles/108-surya-namaskar-what-is-the-right-schedule-to-follow/, which touts the 108 repetitions.

But I get confused with the following

> You know your body best, know your limits and be prepared for a delay
>   of a couple of days before you reach your ultimate goal of 54 sets of
>   Sun salutations.

I understand that one set of Surya Namaskar is a set of identical exercises, working the left and right sides of the body.

So I guess someone can count one set of Surya Namaskar as two rounds, i.e.

`1 set = 2 repititions of yoga`

Help, I am really confused.

Do they mean make 54 sets, i.e. 108 repetitions, or 108 sets?

I am thinking they mean 54 sets (i.e. one set around the Sun), but now I'm not too sure.

[image]

Any of you doing this?

Comment: I think you'd better ask it on a hinduism/yoga tradition forum. From a fitness perspective, it does not matter. For all versions you mention, your exercise will be in the endurance zone. Your question is similar to "if I want to walk 108 steps, should I count it per leg or per two legs?". The answer is: do as many as you like and can!

Comment: so does 1 cycle mean 2 rounds ?

Answer (score 3):

so 108 sun salutations.One Suryanamaskar contains 12 asanas that complete one cycle, so one cycle per each leg (Right & left) complete one round. So 54 sets of this round will give 108 Sun salutations. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do it is not the *hatha sin* salutation that is all one but the Right and then only the Left. I do the [Ashtanga vinyasa suryanamaskara A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CXO5Eq97F8), which is only one. And I do the 108. I have heard some people do 54 *suryanamaskara* A and 54 *suryanamaskara* B.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a picture

Comment: The button to attach a picture is in the bar just above where you type your answer.

Comment: You don't even need to have the image hosted anywhere. One of the options is to upload the picture to Stack Exchange whereupon it builds the link for you.

Answer (score 1):

1 set = 2 rounds
54 sets = 108 rounds

Answer (score 0):

In one round of suryanamaskar you use both legs. In third step you stretch the left leg. At 8th step you stretch the right leg.